# How to use T(Math)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use **T(math).floor**,
but it says Exception evaluation SpringEL expression:

MyCode

```
startPage = ${T(Math).floor(pageNumber / pageSize) * pageSize + 1}">
```

Exception

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "T(Math).floor(pageNumber / pageSize) * pageSize + 1" (template: "/testCase/projectList" - line 24, col 13)

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "T(Math).floor(pageNumber / pageSize) * pageSize + 1" (template: "/testCase/projectList" - line 24, col 13)


Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E: Type cannot be found 'Math'
```

I don't know why not.

Comment: There should be more details about what is causing the exception under that line... but you could try `T(java.lang.Math)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fully qualified class name `java.lang.Math`, since SPeL doesn't see any imports.